# How are plated through holes (PTH) made?

Tags: pcb

I want to know how plated through holes (PTH) are made. Also, what chemicals are used in it and with what quantity?

Comment: This comes to mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered here at the level of detail you seem to be requesting. It seems like you are asking for a recipe. This ends up being more like a chemistry or manufacturing process question and really not about engineering.

Answer (score 3):

In general, PTHs are done in two basic steps.

1) A very thin (1 micron thick) conductive layer is deposited on the hole walls.

2) A thicker layer of copper is electroplated over the thin layer.

The thin layer is the tricky part. Classically, this is done by depositing electroless copper on the board. All sorts of different chemicals can be used, although the most common involves copper sulphate, sulphuric and hydrochloric acid, sodium hydroxide, formaldehyde, and several other chemicals in small quantityl, including a catalyst solution containing palladium and tin. Google "electroless copper plating solution" for sources. The process is not very DIY-friendly, but you can buy the solutions. A special problem is disposing of used solutions, and maintaining the solution chemistries over any sort of long term is a challenge for hobbyists.

Recently, the use of conductive inks, usually containing graphite, has become popular in the industry. A big advantage of these inks is that finicky control of process chemistry is unnecessary.

There is a third technique which involves depositing a copper-bearing chemical on the hole walls, then pyrolyzing the material to leave behind a copper film. This is attractive for hobbyists, but the material needed can also be used in methamphetamine production, so it is a List I precursor and buying it will bring you to the attention of the Feds, who have no sense of humor or proportion on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of the quantity, I imagine it is quite a bit though. According to this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GVk_hEMjzs) @ 3:39, it's an electroplating process.

Also check out https://www.thinktink.com/stack/volumes/volvi/copplate.htm. Typically an acid copper solution is used.

Comment: PTH is done in a variety of ways. *Links are not trusted to last*, so you need real bona fide answers to the question. Copy and paste some of what you found (as quoted text) so we always have at least some paragraphs that answer the question(s). Then you would get upvotes instead of downvotes. I did not downvote you, but others will.